# How to process multiple files fetched using openFileDialog using Streamreader class?

Tags: c#, .net

How to read two files which I have fecthed from the `openFileDialog` box? Below is the code which I have written.

```
private void loadBatchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ExtractSerializedAction>));
    StreamReader myReader = null;
    foreach(string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
    {
        myReader = new StreamReader(file);
    }

    var result = serializer.Deserialize(myReader) as List<ExtractSerializedAction>;
    myReader.Close();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        //some code here
    };
}
```

The above code only fetches the last file which I select using the `openFileDialog`. I know the problem is with the `Streamreader` logic and the `foreach` loop. But dont know how to resolve that?

Comment: Just put everything below the `foreach(string file...)` loop inside the `foreach` loop. The way it is now, you're just setting the StreamReader each time and exiting. So by the time it hits the serializer, it is pointing to the last file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
foreach(string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
{
  using(StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(file))
   {
     var result = serializer.Deserialize(myReader) as List<ExtractSerializedAction>;

  foreach (var item in result)
  {
      //some code here
  }
 }
}
```

**Note :** You can declare the StreamReader object myReader inside using block as shown in my code so you can remove the `StreamReader` object declaration(following statement) outside the for loop.

```
StreamReader myReader = null; //remove this
```

Comment: This is the approach I would recommend in addition to my comment. Using a `using` block makes sure the reader is closed/disposed by doing a `try {} finally { reader.Dispose(); }`